# How to configure using composite attributes to create partition key for my dynamodb table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a DynamoDB table using a CloudFormation template.

```
SomeTable:
    Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
    Properties:
      TableName: !Sub ${AWS::Region}-${InstanceId}-my-table
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: some_field
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: some_field
          KeyType: HASH
```

This all works fine.

But instead of using just one field as my partition key, I want to combine multiple fields to form the partition key.

```
field_one#field_two#field_three
```

Basically, `#` delimited column names.

Is there a way to achieve this in CloudFormation?

Comment: Is your question how to specify a sort key so that it can be used alongside the hash key as a *composite key* so to speak? Or how to concatenate multiple fields for the hash key that you have in your template above?

Comment: I want my primary key to be composed of 3 attributes (columns) separated by a "#". For eg. my primary_key should be "${name}#${age}#${gender}"

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean the actual name of the hash key or that you want to get an item using 3 attribute values as the key?

Comment: concatenate multiple fields for the hash key that you have in your template above.  This is precisely what I need.

Comment: You can't have more than 2 fields as a primary key in DynamoDB- you can use LSI (local secondary indexes) in a hacky way but DynamoDB can only use 1 hash key & 1 sort key. That's a database limitation I'm afraid - does that answer your question?

Comment: Can't I create a primary key which is a concatenation of two(or more..) column values ? If yes, then do I need to store the concatenation in a new separate column or is there is a way to do it without involving 3rd column?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238037/discussion-between-naxi-and-ermiya-eskandary).